# TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on this script below, which is supposed to display the date a row of data was last modified in sheets, but I keep getting the same error message 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined '. I am very new to this, so I would be curious if anyone has any tips or tricks to make it go away. Thanks

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();
  
  if(col === 14 && row > 1 && e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() === "Universe" ){
    e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(row,14).setValue(new Date());

}



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (e.range.columnStart == 14 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && sh.getName() == "Universe") {
    sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart, 14).setValue(new Date());
  }
}
```

You can not run these functions from the script editor unless you supply the event object.

Comment: I don't know if this should work like this, but now, if I type anything in column 3, it replaces it with the current date, however, if I type anything anywhere else, it doesn't actually do anything. Thanks for the contribution though.

Comment: Nvm I typed it in again, and now it works. Thanks a lot.